# Initializing a class in a node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I'm trying to build a class in a node.js module, where I pass a bunch of data into the module when it is required, the module page sets up an initialized state for the class, and then when the a call is made to the module, I create a new class which already has all the initialized data.

Here's a simplified example of my code.

```
function MyClass() {};

function convert_to_object(json_obj, obj) {
    //this converts our json object into a javascript object with prototype
    Object.keys(json_obj).forEach(function(key) {
        obj[key] = json_obj[key];
    });
    return obj;
}

function buildClass(config) {

    try {
        convert_to_obj(config, MyClass); //add a bunch of properties to the object

        MyClass.prototype.init = function(variable) { // initialize the object with a new request
            this.variable = variable;
            return this;
        }
        // I do a bunch of other stuff here, but this is where the issue is
    } catch (e) {
        MyClass.error('error building class:' + e);
        // if there is an error, return the error
    } finally {
        return MyClass;
    }
}

function get_core(variable) {
    if (!variable) {
        return MyClass
    }
    var new_class = new MyClass();
    console.log(new_class);
    new_class.init(variable);
    return new_class;
}

module.exports = function(config) {
    buildClass(config);
    return get_core;
}
```

The output where I am logging the 'new_class' returns

```
{}
```

I can't seem to figure out why my class isn't being initialized as I'd hoped it would.

The way I'm thinking this works is that when I import the module, I pass in the config. This calls the 'buildClass' with the config, and that should set set the new properties on the MyClass object, essentially, initializing the class.

```
var exported_class = require('myclass.js');
```

Then when I want to use the class, I call

```
exported_class('my_variable');
```

It will check that I have passed in a variable, and if so, it will make a copy of the class, which should have all the initialization properties set, and then it will call the init function with my new passed in property.

Comment: `MyClass.prototype.init`, you are directly calling it. Where is it defined?

Comment: Also, is `buildClass` missing `function` keyword?

Comment: You are correct @thefourtheye I did forget the function on buildClass,  and I called the prototype.init rather than defining it. Sorry about that, bad code copying in trying to show a simple version.

Comment: You can check out how the coffescript guys do it [here](http://coffeescript.org/#classes).  I'm lazy and just use coffeescript myself, but it's a good show on how to fake classes in js.

Comment: We have a classic [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem) here. Without asking us how to fix your solution, ask us how to solve your problem.